# Jquery Tab not working on Firefox and chrome. Same works on IE 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I am make several js code changes few days back to a website. Tabs where working fine today i notice that tabs are not working i am not able to locate the source of error.

Tab functionality breaks on FF, Chrome and safari.

link for webpage http://tinyurl.com/qxeu7f

Tabs work on IE 9. this sort of behavior i am not able to understand.

Tabs are working on mobile devices also on different browsers..

Any help in this regards is appreciated.

UPDATE:

Problem was due to One of the Div element was overlapping the Tabs so click even was not able to fire. Removing the `position:relative` from the css for footer div resolved the problem

Comment: For some reason your modernirz.custom.js returns html and not javascript as it should. Could be related.

Comment: console shows Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <  error on modernirz.custom.js

Comment: I tried removing modernizer js but it didnt solve the issue..

Comment: I request all of you to resize the window. once you will resize window to less than 800 pixels you will see tabs start working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.footer-wrapper` element is overflowing the menu. Remove `position: relative;` from `.footer-wrapper` to solve:

```
.footer-wrapper {
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*position: relative;*/
  width: 1000px;
}
```